# Binding Semantic-UI module events in Meteor Template.events

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze, semantic-ui

Instead of using jQuery, I would like to bind callbacks to Semantic-UI modules the "Meteor-way", a bit like Bootstrap 3 allows for, e.g.:

```js
Template.someTemplate.events({
  'show.bs.dropdown .someDropdown': function () {
    // official Bootstrap JS callback for the Dropdown module's show event
  }
});
```

With Semantic-UI it seems like I can only define the callback functions when using jQuery bindings in the containing Template's `onRendered()` callback, e.g.:

```js
Template.someTemplate.onRendered( function () {
  this.$('.someDropdown').dropdown({
    'onShow': function () {
      // official Semantic-UI JS callback for the Dropdown module's show event
    }
  });
});
```

This isn't optimal because (a) other DOM elements might not be ready for manipulation during a particular Template's `onRendered()` callback, and (b) it makes separation of concerns & code clarity far harder to achieve.

Is there a way to bind these events using Meteor's `Template.events`, and if so, what is the correct syntax to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer to [this Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856527/meteor-binding-values-for-inputs-with-event-generation/32859904#32859904)

As described in the Solution The best way to Bind the UI is using `manuel:viewmodel`

You keep the state of the UI in a javascript object and bind the UI elements to properties of that object.

Documentation can be found [here](http://viewmodel.meteor.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's a good-looking package. However, binding custom variables & functions to the Template DOM isn't what I'm looking for. I'm simply seeking the Meteor events-driven syntax to bind native Semantic-UI module events. I want to avoid adding extra packages that introduce more complexity. Any reactive variables and helpers that I need for the DOM are already part of the Template, making the `viewmodel` package not quite for my purposes just now.

Answer (score 0):

my solution

html

```
<div class="ui search selection dropdown" id="dataDropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="applications">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Application</div>
  <div class="menu" >
    {{#each data}}
      <div class="item" data-value={{id}}>
        {{name}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
//can catch 2 events when searching then clicking on a dropdown item. 
//first event is the change of the input text. second event is the dropdown
//change. we only want the values associated with the dropdown change, thus
//we use the if check
change #appDropdown': function(event, template) {
  if (event.target.type === 'text'){
    return;
  }
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
```